# Spacing items in box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with spacing between objects in a box.

I have a container with items:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

But when I add more objects or resize window it destroy responsiveness.
I want to get 3 or more in a row. Container will have `flex-wrap`. And every first and last box in a row didn't have spacing/margin at the point of contact with the box like in the picture below.

[image]

I tried `justify-content: space-between`, disable margin and others.

Is there a way to easily make it responsive?

Answer (score 2):

Put The CSS like below Hope it will work fine.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body,html{
  width:100%;

}
.container {
  width:90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.3333% - 2rem - 2px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:15px 0;
  height:150px;
  min-width:150px;
  display:inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center
}

@media only screen and (min-width:576px){
  .container{
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    display:
  }
  .box:nth-child(3n-1){
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
  <div class='box'>3</div>
  <div class='box'>4</div>
  <div class='box'>5</div>
  <div class='box'>6</div>
  <div class='box'>7</div>
  <div class='box'>8</div>
  <div class='box'>9</div>
</div>
```

I hope I understood your question correctly, and you wanted to have margins :) If you open the snippet in full page you can play with the screen size and see how the divs will work.